# Using self_value in another class

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I'm trying to learn more about classes so I've built a deck of cards using multiple classes. The goal is to be able to play multiple card games with the deck.
I have a basic class, called PlayingCard:

```
class PlayingCard:
def __init__(self, suit, value):
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = value
```

And different sub-classes for the numbered cards, the jack cards, the queen cards etc. defined as:

```
class NumberedCards(PlayingCard):
def __init__(self, suit, value):
    self.value = value
    super().__init__(suit, self.value)

class JackCard(PlayingCard):
    def __init__(self, suit):
        self.value = 11
        super().__init__(suit, self.value)

...and so on
```

I then build my deck of cards in a new class, 'Deck':

```
class Deck:
def __init__(self):
    self.deck = []

def create_deck(self):
    for suit in Suit:
        for i in range(2, 11):
            self.deck.append(NumberedCards(suit.value, i))
        self.deck.append(JackCard(suit.value))
        ...
```

Lastly, I have a class called Hand:

```
class Hand:
def __init__(self):
    self.hand = []
```

where I have functions to draw cards from the deck and place them in `self.hand`

I now want to create yet another class with different functions, where I can use a `Hand()`-instance to check if there's for example any pairs in the hand or if there's a straight etc. 
I have something like this in mind:

```
class BestHand:
def __init__(self):
    ...

def check_pairs(self, cards):
    """Here, for example, I want to extract the value of
    each card on hand and put them in a new list for easier comparison"""
```

where I then can check the cards in the hand by calling something in the style of

```
hand = Hand()
test = BestHand()
test.check_pairs(hand)
```

The problem is that I can't extract the value from the hand-cards. I realize they're only defined as `self.value` in the class PlayingCard, but is there a way to extract them to use in the BestHand class?

Comment: the values would be `[card.value for card in hand.hand]`

Comment: In your instance of the class `Hand()` (you called it `hand`) you have the list `hand` stored as an object attribute. Therefore to access this list you need to access `hand.hand`

Answer (score 1):

You have an object called hand, it is of type `Hand` meaning it has an attribute called `hand` which is  list of `Card` objects. `hand.hand` is the list of `Card` objects in that object. `[card.value for card in hand.hand]` will get the value for each card in that list of cards